# Pseudoexperiments in PyMC

Tags: python, bayesian, pymc

Is it possible to perform "pseudoexperiments" using PyMC?

By pseudoexperiments, I mean generating random "observations" by sampling from the prior, and then, given each pseudoexperiment, drawing samples from the posterior.  Afterwards, one would compare the trace for each parameter to the sample (obtained from the prior) used in sampling from the posterior.

A more concrete example:  Suppose that I want to know the rate of process X.  I count how many occurrences there are in a certain period of time.  However, I know that process Y also sometimes occurs and will contaminate my count.  The rate of process Y is known with some uncertainty.  So, I build a model, include my observations, and sample from the posterior:

```
import pymc

class mymodel:
    rate_x = pymc.Uniform('rate_x', lower=0, upper=100)
    rate_y = pymc.Normal('rate_y', mu=150, tau=1./(15**2))
    total_rate = pymc.LinearCombination('total_rate', [1,1], [rate_x, rate_y])
    data = pymc.Poisson('data', mu=total_rate, value=193, observed=True)

Mod = pymc.Model(mymodel)
MCMC = pymc.MCMC(Mod)
MCMC.sample(100000, burn=5000, thin=5)
print MCMC.stats()['rate_x']['quantiles']
```

However, before I do my experiment (or before I "unblind" my analysis and look at my data), I would like to know how sensitive I expect to be -- what will be the uncertainty on my measurement of rate_x?

To answer this, I could sample from the prior

```
Mod.draw_from_prior()
```

but this only samples `rate_x`, `rate_y`, and calculates `total_rate`.  But once the values of those are set by `draw_from_prior()`, I can draw a pseudoexperiment:

```
Mod.data.random()
```

This just returns a number, so I have to set the value of `Mod.data` to a random sample.  Because `Mod.data` has the `observed` flag set, I have to also "force" it:

```
Mod.data.set_value(Mod.data.random(), force=True)
```

Now I can sample from the posterior again

```
MCMC.sample(100000, burn=500, thin=5)
print MCMC.stats()['rate_x']['quantiles']
```

All this works, so I suppose the simple answer to my question is "yes".  But it feels very hacky.  Is there a better or more natural way to accomplish this?